# Press a button based on action

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I would like to press a button which have in button tags this option:

```
<div aria-controllers="my-list"> Press for more information </div>
```

Which call from R selenium should I use?

This is what I tried:

```
webElem1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'aria-controllers', value = 'my-list')
webElem1$sendKeysToElement(list('R', key = 'enter'))
```

Also if I use this I receive the following error:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'aria-controllers', value = "my-list")
Error in match.arg(using) : 
  'arg' should be one of “xpath”, “css selector”, “id”, “name”, “tag name”, “class name”, “link text”, “partial link text”
```

Comment: any help please what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know R but I think what you need is

```
webElem1 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', value = 'div[aria-controllers="my-list"]')
```

The first argument is the type of locator, that's why you got the error listing all the locator types like 'id', 'css selector', etc. I chose a CSS selector because I think that best matches the way you are trying to locate the element.

The second argument is the locator itself. In this case, the CSS selector.

You probably should spend some time looking at the documentation.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html#search-using-css-selectors

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/seleniumPipes/versions/0.3.7/topics/findElement

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion but I receive this error: `Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
   Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.`

Comment: Since I can't see the page, you would have to look and see why. Check for an `IFRAME` or add a wait and see if that helps.